# Spam Classification Lab: Python Error in Array Syntax

Tags: python, arrays, syntax

I receive an invalid syntax error for this code... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#show the vectors for each sentence
print(X.toarray()) 

[[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0] 

[0 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0] 

[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0] 

[1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]]
```

Comment: What is `X`? And what are you trying to do in the lines after the `print` statement?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mate simply try this with Numpy

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(X)

print(arr)
```

In case you're solving a text based problem like converting words to vectors, then I'll recommend you use the Tokenizer from Tensorflow library. Use the following code then.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.text.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

sentences = [
'This is sample one',
'This is sample two'
]

tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words = 100)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(word_index)
```

Try this.
Hope this helps.